# ReactJs and API help "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

So im really new to reactJS and been trying to make an app that will pick a random and with the help of the movie data bases api pick one. I've mainly learnt from youtube videos but have been struggling to find one that helps with linking api's this is the one I've been using [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=204C9yNeOYI&t=2403s][1]

I've got to the point where im just getting this error and im not sure what I've done wrong.

```
    App._callee$
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/src/App.js:34
  31 | 
  32 | getFilm = async(e) => {
  33 |   e.preventDefault();
> 34 |   const title = e.target.elements.title;
  35 |   const overview = e.target.elements.overview;
  36 |   const poster_path = e.target.elements.poster_path;
  37 |   const vote_average = e.target.elements.vote_average;
View compiled
▼ 23 stack frames were expanded.
tryCatch
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62
Generator.invoke [as _invoke]
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296
Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114
step
http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:41550:191
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:41550:437
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:41550:99
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:41625:22
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:438
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:452
executeDispatch
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:836
executeDispatchesInOrder
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:858
executeDispatchesAndRelease
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:956
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:967
forEachAccumulated
C:/Users/KJ_pi/Desktop/app/website/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:935
processEventQueue
```

It feels like I'm a bit over my head in all of this but its for an internship position and I've gained a lot of experience so far doing just looking for a little guidance if I've missed anything please let me know

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
//Components
import Header from './components/headerComponent/header';
import Footer from './components/footerComponent/footer';
import HomePage from './components/pages/frontpage/homepage';
import RandomFilm from './components/pages/randomfilm/randomFilm';
import Genre from './components/pages/Genre/genre';

// Includes
import './Assets/css/default.min.css';
const API_KEY = "7cab3fa448c3344f96941896421ea986";



class App extends Component {

state ={
  title: undefined,
overview: undefined,
poster_path: undefined,
vote_average: undefined
}




  getFilm = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const title = e.target.elements.title;
    const overview = e.target.elements.overview;
    const poster_path = e.target.elements.poster_path;
    const vote_average = e.target.elements.vote_average;
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=${API_KEY}`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data);

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">

      <Header/>
      <RandomFilm getFilm={this.getFilm}/>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path='/genre' component={Genre}/>
      <Footer />

      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My app.js file

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';



class RandomFilm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="main">
      <h1> Lets see what you got</h1>
      <div name="title">
      </div>
      <div name="overview">
      </div>
      <div name="poster_path">
      </div>
      <div name="vote_average">
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.props.getFilm}>Randomize</button>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default RandomFilm;
```

randomfilm.js

Comment: This likely just means that `e.target` on line 34 does not have an `elements`; in this case, I'm assuming that means there are no child elements of that event target.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual code, though.

Comment: Ive updated with my code not sure if it helps

Comment: Why don't you try some basic debugging? That's what helps me. Inside of `getFilm`, at the top, try `console.log(e.target)` and see what you get. If that is what you expected, `console.log(e.target.elements)`, and so on and so forth. I still think that `e.target` doesn't have an `elements` prop, which probably means `e.target` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Your `e.target` is your submit button. It won't have an `elements` property like what you are searching for. Are you trying to set those values based on the data you get back from the api? Or are you trying to read those values from inputs?

Comment: Im wanting to display them once ive got them from the api

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this - I hope this helps with your question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {apikey} from './data';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: '',
      overview: '',
      poster: '',
      vote: ''
    }
    this.getFilm=this.getFilm.bind(this);
  }

  getFilm(){
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=${apikey}`
    axios.get(url)
    .then(data => {
      let res = data.data;
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        title: res.title,
        overview: res.overview,
        poster: res.homepage+res.poster_path,
        vote: res.vote_average

      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.poster);
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <h1> Lets see what you got</h1>
      <div name="title">
        {this.state.title}
      </div>
      <div name="overview">
        {this.state.overview}
      </div>
      <div name="poster_path">
        <a href={this.state.poster}>Link Movie - Click Here!</a>
      </div>
      <div name="vote_average">
        {this.state.vote}
      </div>
        <button onClick={this.getFilm}>Get Movie</button>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Just wondering but is the app.js fine? and this is just for the randomFilm.js thank you so much for taking the time to help